# R add tweaks to interaction plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to modify this graph:

- Shorten the lines to only display from -1 SD to + 1SD for the weight variable
- Cap each line with a square or triangle symbol
- Change the x-axis to display Low weight and High weight instead of the digits and tick marks.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat=mtcars
mod <- lm(mpg ~ gear * wt, data=dat)

apatheme=theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(),
        text=element_text(family='Times'),
        legend.title=element_blank())

p=ggplot(dat, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = gear))+
  geom_blank()+
  labs(x = 'Vehicle Weight', y = 'Vehicle MPG')+
  scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE)+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=33.965, slope=-4.3985, linetype='-1SD Gear'))+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=42.2767, slope=-7.3095, linetype='+1SD Gear'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('dotted','dashed','solid'),
                        breaks=c('-1SD Gear','Mean Gear','+1SD Gear'),name='Simple\nSlope')+
  apatheme
p
```

Here is what it currently produces

[image]

I am trying to get it closer to this APA style version

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `geom_segment` instead of `geom_abline`?

Comment: No! Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to plot based on SD difference from the mean, would start with calculating mean and SD on your variables on interest. You can then construct a data frame containing the points you want to include for specific values of `gear` and `wt`.

Instead of using numbers for slope/intercept, would `predict` values of `mpg` based on `gear` and `wt` using your model `mod`.

I added some factors/labels based on your desired figure.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

dat=mtcars
mod <- lm(mpg ~ gear * wt, data=dat)

dat_sum <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ 1, dat, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))

df <- data.frame(
  gear = with(dat_sum, c(gear.mean - gear.sd, gear.mean + gear.sd, gear.mean - gear.sd, gear.mean + gear.sd)),
  gear_lab = factor(c("Low Gears", "High Gears", "Low Gears", "High Gears"), levels = c("Low Gears", "High Gears")),
  wt = with(dat_sum, c(wt.mean - wt.sd, wt.mean - wt.sd, wt.mean + wt_sd, wt.mean + wt.sd)),
  wt_lab = factor(c("Low Weight", "Low Weight", "High Weight", "High Weight"), levels = c("Low Weight", "High Weight")))

df$mpg <- predict(mod, df)

apatheme=theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(),
        text=element_text(family='Times'),
        legend.title=element_blank())

ggplot(df, aes(x = wt_lab, y = mpg, group = gear_lab))+
  geom_point(aes(shape = gear_lab))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = gear_lab))+
  ylim(0,30)+
  labs(x = 'Vehicle Weight', y = 'Vehicle MPG')+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 17))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dotted', 'dashed'))+
  apatheme
```

**Plot**

[image: APA style plot]

Comment: thanks for posting. I'm trying to get this to run in my RStudio. Can you explain this line: dat_sum <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ 1, dat, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))). What does the ~ 1 do?

Comment: @KevinT There are different ways to get mean and standard deviation on the different variables, I chose `aggregate` though others would work as well. Try some simple `aggregate` statements to get familiar with it. For example, from the `iris` dataset, you can do: `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, mean)` and this will compute the `mean` `Sepal.Length` by `Species` (3 mean values for 3 Species). If you use `.` (dot) in the formula instead of `Sepal.Length` it will return means of all variables in the dataset (Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, etc.)...

Comment: The `. ~ 1` in `aggregate` simply does not subset further. It will just compute means (and standard deviations in the above example) overall and not by subgroup. That's all.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, I am actually of course trying to graph something more complex than the mt_cars example I used in the reprex. I am trying to graph an interact and my model is much more complex. I think I have it working except for the predict function. Do you have any guidance on how I would call the predict function with this model:

Comment: model.interactions.4 <- lm(posemo.t1.t2 ~ 
                         gender_d.cent + first_time_founder_d.cent +
                         num_years_in_business.cent + statuses_count.cent + 
                         communion.cent +
                         agency.cent + dispersion_count.cent + 
                         (agency.cent * dispersion_count.cent),
                      data = m_vars)

Comment: I was able to get this to work with my more complex interaction model. Thanks for providing the solution!